# Create nested arrays that mimic a grid using for loops

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, nested-loops

I am trying to make nested arrays that mimic a grid using for loops. I want it to look like this:

```
[[0, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 0]]
```

I have been able to create one line of the array like so

```
[0, 0, 0]
```

using

```
var num = 3;
var arr = [];
for (var j = 0; j < num; j++) {
  arr[j] = 0;
}
console.log(arr);
```

I stuck with how to implement nesting the second for loop around the first. My thought would be to push the finished output of the inner loop to the i index of of the outer loop. So something like

```
var num = 3;
var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < num; j++) {
    arr[j] = 0;
  }
  // some command here to push the completed output of the inner output to i index of the outer loop
}
console.log(arr);
```

I am on the right track with this? If not, where do I need to shift my thinking here? I haven’t been able to get a solution that produces the desired outcome yet.

Answer (score 1):

You just needed to initialize the subarray for each set, then utilize both counters to place your '0'

```js
var num = 3;
var arr = [];
for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
  arr[i] = [];
  for (let j = 0; j < num; j++) {
    arr[i][j] = 0;
  }
}
console.log(arr);
```